# Why dont request.getParameter("html_control_id") work in AJAX call in JSP?

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am sending ajax request from 1 JSP to other JSP. In called JSP when I try to get value of a HTML control with the help of request.getParameter("HTML_control_name/id") It returns null.

Comment: Post the code you have tried . the jsp pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> request.getParameter("HTML_control_name/id")

request.getParameter() returns the string of the parameters sent in the HTTP Requests.

You can get the value of your form attributes through `request.getParameter("Name Of form Attribute")`